# Django .save() method not saving

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-database

I'm trying to save a text imput from an HTML page, and then display it on a redirect. It seems that the .save() method isn't working. I'm quite new to Django and HTML in general. I've followed the official Django tutorial and trying to apply the concepts from that into this app. Basically, it is supposed to take a user input from an HTML page and then save it to a list of names. Then, I want to redirect to another page which displays a list of these names. Anyone have any ideas? Here's my code:

In views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, redirect
from .models import Contact

def addListing(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    new_contact = Contact(
        full_name=request.POST['fullname'],
        )
    new_contact.save()
    return redirect('listings')

return render(request, 'farmsearch/add_listing.html')

def listings(request):
farms = Contact.objects.all()
return render(request, 'farmsearch/listings.html', {'farms': farms})
```

In models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.full_name
```

In add_listing.html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'farmsearch:listings' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="farm_name">Farm name: </label>
            <input type="text" class="type" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In listings.html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for farm in farms %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ farm.new_farm }}</p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `{{ farm.full_name }}`

Comment: If you know is a new object model you must use `obj = Contacts.objects.create(cleaneddatafromtheform)` and `obj.save()`